# I have written a python code for the collatz pattern for number and I want to count the number of steps it took to reach 1. How can I do it?

Tags: python, collatz

```
def collatz(n):
    while n > 1:
        print(n, end=' ')
        if (n % 2):
            # n is odd
            n = 3*n + 1
        else:
            # n is even
            n = n//2
    print(1, end='')
 
 
n = int(input('Enter n: '))
print('Sequence: ', end='')
collatz(n)
```

Comment: Add and increase a counter variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a counter

```
def collatz(n):
    counter = 0
    while n > 1:
        counter += 1
        print(n, end=' ')
        if (n % 2):
            # n is odd
            n = 3*n + 1
        else:
            # n is even
            n = n//2
    print(1, end='\n')
    print("Number of steps until convergance :" + str(counter))
 
 
n = int(input('Enter n: '))
print('Sequence: ', end='')
collatz(n)
```

Comment: thanks a lot btw if I want to count the number of numbers (obtained through collatz) which are divisible by 2 how can I do it?

Comment: Move the counter += 1 to the else statement

Comment: @Sumit It seems like this answers your question. Please accept and close the question.